# How to pass the onClick() event to a child component from a button in the parent component in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Let's say I have two components Component1 and Component2. I have a button in Component1.

```
const Component1 = () => {
    return(
        <div>
        <button onClick={()=>someExportFunc()}>Export</button>
        <Component2 />
    </div>
    )
}
```

My `Component2.jsx` is something like this.

```
import {ChartComponent} from '@xyz/charts';

    
const Component2 = () => {
    let chartInstance = new ChartComponent();

    return (
                <ChartComponent
                id='chart1'
                ref={chart = chartInstance => chart}

                >

                </ChartComponent>
        )

}
```

Now the function `someExportFunc()` is defined inside the `{ChartComponent}` being imported in `Component2.jsx`.

Had I used the button inside Component2, it would have worked simply. As in,

```
import {ChartComponent} from '@xyz/charts'

    
const Component2 = () => {
    let chartInstance = new ChartComponent();

    return (
                <button onClick={()=>someExportFunc()}>Export</button>
               <ChartComponent
                id='chart1'
                ref={chart = chartInstance => chart}

                >

                </ChartComponent>
        )

}
```

But how can I make it work as a button in Component1?

I am guessing it has something to do with defining state of the button and then passing the state down, but I don't exactly understand how the state of a button works. `onClick()` should be some instantaneous boolean, isn't it? By instantaneous, I mean it would change as soon as the 'click' is over.

**Edit1**: Okay, so the `someExportFunc()` is a library function defined in my import. It makes use of the `chartInstance` created in Component2. It's actual use case is

```
<button 
   value='export'
   onClick={() => chartInstance.exportModule.export('PNG', 
       `image`)}>
        Export
      </button>
```

So basically I want it so that when I click the button within Component1, it sends the onClick event to my ChartComponent in Component2.

Answer (score 2):

we need to pass the function as a prop to the second component.

**FirstComponent**

```
<SecondComponent { ...data } onClick={ () => manageClick() } />
```

in the second Component use the onClick prop on click.

**SecondComponent**

```
<button onClick={onClick}>Click</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

React uses one-way data binding, meaning parent to child in this case.

If Component 2 is a child of Component 1, define the function in Component 1 and pass the function and Chart Component as props and children respectively.

Parent:

```
const Component1 = () => {
  const someFunc = () => {...}
  return <Component2 someFunc={someFunc}> <ChartComponent/> </Component2>
}
```

Child:

```
const Component2 = (props) => {
  props.someFunc();
  return <div> {props.children} </div>
}
```

Comment: While this doesn't exactly answer my question, it made me realise what I was trying to do was kind of like two-way data binding. The function is already defined in the ChartComponent which is a library component. I was trying to pass the button onClick event to the child and then somehow call a certain method within the child. It was complicating things unnecessarily. So I just simplified the structure.